# Length of the straight path connecting two points in the taxicab geometry? Are such straight paths even permissible in this geometry?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let's equip $\mathbb R^2$ with the [taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) induced by the norm $||\cdot||_1$.

[image]

Now let's look at this image on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). The caption says "Taxicab geometry versus Euclidean distance: In taxicab geometry, the red, yellow, and blue paths all have the same shortest path length of 12. In Euclidean geometry, the green line has length $6\sqrt 2 \approx 8.49$ and is the unique shortest path." Let's name the black point at the bottom left as $A$ and the black point at the top right as $B$.

Indeed, I understand that the red path, blue path and the yellow path all have the same length of $12$ units in this taxicab geometry. However, is there a notion of path length of the straight green line connecting $A$ and $B$ in this taxicab geometry? What's the length of the green line connecting $A$ and $B$ in this geometry? Or can such a path not even exist in this geometry? Are other "curved" paths between $A$ and $B$ permissible? Why or why not?

I'm a bit confused about this issue. I keep seeing only these grid-like paths in all texts explaining taxicab geometry, but none of them explain the reason. Are other kinds of paths not permissible somehow? Some clarification would help.

Comment: How do you define arc length in this metric? The natural meaning "length" of a straight line is the distance between its endpoints according to the taxicab metric. For a curve you have a limiting process (which may or may not be well-defined). I think the circumference of a circle comes out as $4d$ where $d$ is the diameter.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks. Is that limiting process called the *rectification* of a curve, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length)? I think I can visualize the straight green line as a limiting case of the zig-zag blue line, by making the horizontal and vertical stretches smaller and smaller.

Comment: "The natural meaning "length" of a straight line is the distance between its endpoints according to the taxicab metric. ": Isn't there a difference between the zig-zag and oblique lines in this geometry? Also how did you get to the conclusion that the length of a straight line in the taxicab metric is simply the distance between its endpoints?

Comment: The primitive concept here is the distance between two points. See my comment on the proposed answer - every "ladder" has the same length so the limit is the limit of a constant function.

Comment: @MarkBennet Right. Right. Makes sense now! Your comment on the existing answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reasonable thing to be confused about.  Presentations of taxicab geometry don't do any favors when they model it too closely after grid-based cities.  The distance  from $(0,0.5)$ to $(1,0.5)$ is one, even though a cab couldn't get you from the middle of a block of 14th Street to the middle of the same block of 15th street in a straight line.

In a taxicab geometry, you can certainly talk about the green line segment, just like you could think about any other set of points in the plane.  But the length of the line segment is $d_T(A,B)=12$, as all of the other paths demonstrate.

There are other interesting phenomena that distinguish horizontal and vertical line segments from oblique line segments like $\overline{AB}$.  For instance, if two points $X,Y$ form a horizontal or vertical line segment, then that line segment is $\{Z\mid d_T(X,Z)+d_T(Y,Z)=d_T(X,Y)\}$, like we're used to for the Euclidean metric.    But, in your diagram, $\{C\mid d_T(A,C)+d_T(B,C)=d_T(A,B)\}$ is the entire rectangle whose opposite corners are $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I get it but one question. How do we rigorously prove that the length of the straight green line is $12$ units? Is it done by showing it as a limiting case of the zig-zag blue line, where we keep making the horizontal and vertical stretches smaller and smaller? Is this what they mean by *rectification* of a curve on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length)?

Comment: @S.D. The taxicab metric itself defines the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ as $|x_2-x_1| + |y_2-y_1|$, so all of those colored paths just give an intuitive explanation of why the straightforward calculation is an interesting metric to consider.

Comment: I get that the distance between $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ in the taxicab metric is $|x_2 - x_1| + |y_2 - y_1|$. I also understand that the lengths of the red, yellow and blue paths in this metric space are all $12$ units. It can be proved by adding the horizontal and vertical stretches for each of the red, yellow and blue paths. However, it is not clear to me that the "length" of the "straight green path" is $12$, without making a limiting case argument of some kind.

Comment: @S.D. You can make the steps of the "ladder" as small as you like (hence the "ladder" as "close" to the diagonal as you like) - but the total length of every "ladder" is the same, so that is the limit.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks, yeah! Exactly. I was thinking of something like that. And I guess that's what they mean by rectification of curves (which is a limiting process) on Wikipedia.